# Logging message data from a dialog to Application Insights in node.js bot based on botframework v4

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am trying to log some user data, namely some feedback from a dialog to application insights.

I want to basically show some statistics regarding the kind of feedback the bot gets on the app insights dashboard.

However, the documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0] only covers the details for C# users, **my bot is coded in node.js**

How can I **log some data from a dialog in a node.js bot to app insights**? My bot is based on the core-bot sample from Microsoft.

For now, I am also saving all the chat transcripts to azure blob storage, but I'm not sure how I can use that.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. I haven't figured out specifically the dialog piece, which is what I know you're asking about, but there are a number of resources I've used to get basically everything but.

- [Analytics for Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-analytics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) (Channel and activity metrics within Bot Service blade)
- [Analytics for nodejs Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) (General analytics within the App Insights blade)
- [Analytics for LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-bot-nodejs-appinsights)
- [Analytics for QnA Maker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base)

I'm assuming that something similar can be built using the generic "Analytics for nodejs Applications", but I don't have enough knowledge on where that dialog information resides to build custom properties. However, if you are looking only for some specific information from the dialogs as opposed to the full suite of analytics as shown in the C# example you linked, you should be able to just create a custom property for that information and send it to App Insights.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs have [TelemetryClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/dialog?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#telemetryclient) class to offer insights into your bot by showing which features are used the most, detects unwanted behavior and offers visibility into availability, performance, and usage. Telemetry logging enables bot applications to send event data to telemetry services such as Application Insights.

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) makes use of the core bot sample and will help you to add telemetry to your bot and enable telemetry in your bot dialogs.

Hope this helps.